# Automatic CheckBoxes in a ListView with MultiChoice Action Mode

Tags: android

[The Common's Ware Multi-Choice Action Mode example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC) appears to use some default behavior of `ListView`. In particular, the `CheckedTextView` in the list's layout becomes checked (or cleared) automatically when the user long-clicks to start the action mode or, if the action mode is already active, when the user clicks on an item. I've started to delve into the source code for AbsListView, and I don't see where it sets the "checked" state. Any ideas how this is accomplished? More importantly, how can I take advantage of this behavior in my own app?

Answer (score 2):

After some further research, I found this method in `AbsListView`:

```
private void updateOnScreenCheckedViews() {
    final int firstPos = mFirstPosition;
    final int count = getChildCount();
    final boolean useActivated = getContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
            >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        final int position = firstPos + i;

        if (child instanceof Checkable) {
            ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
        } else if (useActivated) {
            child.setActivated(mCheckStates.get(position));
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand here, the `ListView` is only able to deal with checkboxes if the direct children of the `ListView` implement `Checkable`. To facilitate complex layouts, I have created a [CheckableLinearLayout](https://github.com/codeguru42/CheckableLinearLayout) component that can be used in this exact situation.